# Spring boot fails to start when add Kubernetes dependencies "The bean 'kubernetesPodUtils', defined in class path resource"

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

I trying to add Kubernetes to my project to use `Service name` rather than `localhost`. I added the below **dependencies** :

```
   @AutoConfigureAfter
    @EnableEurekaClient
    @EnableFeignClients
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
```

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MicroServices -->
```

But I got the below error :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
The bean 'kubernetesPodUtils', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/KubernetesAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/client/KubernetesClientAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
Action:
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
2022-06-14 12:28:08.696 ERROR 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter :
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
The bean 'kubernetesPodUtils', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/KubernetesAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/client/KubernetesClientAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
Action:
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `KubernetesAutoConfiguration` is going to be defined in multiple dependencies. Based on your need, try to identify the dependencies which are required. In your pom file you have `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all` alongwith individual dependecies too.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#starters